# MeteorJS - Fallback for disabled javascript?

Tags: meteor

What's the best way to handle browsers that have javascript turned off (or if the script doesn't load for some reason)? I know less than 5% of people do that these days, but I'd still like to have some sort of fallback if possible.

Comment: on the user group, you can find a discussion here :- https://forums.meteor.com/t/where-does-meteor-stand-on-progressive-enhancement/2382/14

Answer (score 3):

First approach:

You can use a body class:

See the [Meteor website's example](http://noscript.meteor.com/) or:

```
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url('http://www.images.com/bgimg.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
        }

        .has-script{
            background-image: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="has-script">
<h1>Welcome to our website!</h1>

{{> hello}}
```

```
body:not(.has-script) {
      margin-top: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;

      &::before {
        content: "Please enable JavaScript!";
      }
    }
```

Second Approach:

You can save a cached version for the produced HTML templates, and serve them from there.

You can add a cache manifest to a Meteor app like [manifestR](http://westciv.com/tools/manifestR/)

Though I don't know how complex your templates are..

Third Approach and the best one:

Basicly on the browser side, add the noscript code to the head

```
<noscript>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 32px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 100vh;
        }
        body:after {
            content: "Please enable JavaScript in your browser to view this site.";
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

Comment: does that work in meteor?  because meteor doesn't serve html, just javascript that it converts to html

Comment: Your original will work if you put a noscript in the head, but basically you can only say turn on javascript!

Comment: Answer Updated, hope it helps.

Comment: @AbdulRahmanMohsen My site isn't super complicated, but it sounds like if I use <noscript>, I'd either have to copy and paste everything over, or use it to tell the user to turn on javascript.

so the only non copy-pasta option i have seems to be server side rendering?

Comment: @KeithNicholas is there a way to get Meteor to serve any html, at all? :/

Comment: you can do server side routes and serve html